# UnauthorizedAccessException vs IOException

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm listing some folders from Nas share, get folder properties and list sub folders.
for folders where i have no access rights i get two different exceptions

1. `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`: Access to the path 'Z:\info' is denied.
2. `System.IO.IOException`: The network path was not found.

The second one takes long time to be catch which slows down the application

My question is why for some shares i get the network path was not found and others the access denied?
what is the different? and how can i avoid the second exception which takes time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is why for some shares i get the network path was not found and others the access denied? what is the different?

If the path is found quickly, but you don't have permission, you'll receive an `UnauthorizedAccessException` very quickly.

However, if the system is trying to discover whether the network share is even valid, this can take a while.  It will need to do quite a bit of network access before it can determine that the network path isn't valid at all, and this can take time.

> and how can i avoid the second exception which takes time.

The only real way to do this is not to access shares which do not exist.  This isn't always practical - if you need to determine at runtime whether they exist, you'll just need to design around the fact that this may be slow.

There are many ways to improve this, however - if you're checking against multiple shares, you could do these checks in parallel.  Given that this is really IO bound, threading could make a huge difference in overall responsiveness of your application as you can check all of the shares at the same time, instead of sequentially.

Comment: The shares should exists since i do Directory.GetDirectories(root) then i loop through the results, if the share doesn't exists then it should not be listed.

Comment: @Maro "Permanent" mapped drives may still "exist" but not be available.  The OS doesn't actually connect to them until you try to access the drive, which can take a while.

Comment: @Maro That's an optimization for speeding up things like boot times, etc.

Comment: +1 from me, however, the idea of using threading is great, do you have an example as i don't have any experience? + will threading make different for running the application in single processor?

Comment: @Maro Yes, it'll make a huge difference, even on a single processor, since it's IO bound, and not CPU bound.  See http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/20/parallelism-in-net-part-2-simple-imperative-data-parallelism/